# What are the options and constancy of storing file data in NTFS?

Tags: ntfs

I know it has the $DATA attribute, but heard that it's not always include the whole file content due to some circumstances.

I've also heard that *delayed write operations* could make this attribute not fully accurate for indicating the file content.

So - what are the variations/possible structures for holding a file content in NTFS, and what is the constancy according to them?

Answer (score 0):

File data can be stored in $DATA attributes (in unnamed stream, the default one), and/or in alternative data streams (ADS, named $DATA attributes). Another option to store additional metadata about file are extended attributes (in NTFS it's in attribute $EA). Each attribute is a data stream that is managed in kernel by Cache Manager (Cc* API in Windows kernel realm) and Memory Manager (Mm* API). Whole $DATA attribute can be either inside MFT file record, or externalized to disk clusters. Nevertheless, if you use only user mode API, you can disregard all this, system always gives you accurate data.

Comment: If the data was externalized to clusters, how can I detect this?

Comment: I strongly recommend reading up about NTFS, e.g. here, http://www.ntfs.com, but to understand how IFS (installable file systems) requires years of kernel development. Regarding your question, you can tell whether $DATA attribute is residential or not, but even to decode used clusters from the attribute isn't easy task, and frankly I fail to understand why would one want do that, when - again, on low level - you can open a stream on that attribute and simply read it. But I'd avoid kernel mode development unless you have to - even set up an environment for kernel mode development isn't easy.